# get all lines of a continuation line in traceback

Tags: python, traceback

Is it possible to get all lines of a continuation line in a traceback?

Example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
def function_with_long_name(foo, bar):
  raise Exception('problem?')
function_with_long_name('very_important_value',
  'meaningless_value')
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    'meaningless_value')
  File "./test.py", line 3, in function_with_long_name
    raise Exception('problem?')
Exception: problem?
```

Note that it prints only the last line of the continuation line.

I would like to have all lines of the continuation line, something like this:

```
$ ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    function_with_long_name('very_important_value',
      'meaningless_value')
  File "./test.py", line 3, in function_with_long_name
    raise Exception('problem?')
Exception: problem?
```

Is this possible?

I have looked at the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module, but the values it returns are already truncated.

Example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import traceback
def function_with_long_name(foo, bar):
  print traceback.extract_stack()
function_with_long_name('very_important_value',
  'meaningless_value')
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.py 
[('./test.py', 6, '<module>', "'meaningless_value')"), ('./test.py', 4, 'function_with_long_name', 'print traceback.extract_stack()')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone appears to have just opened [Python issue 12458](http://bugs.python.org/issue12458) about this.  Suggest you follow along there.